# How do I install the proxybroker2 repository?

Tags: python, github, repository

Hey I wanted to install the [git hub repository](https://github.com/bluet/proxybroker2), but I am not really sure about the installation process.

I am not really good with python and want to know what steps of the installation guide I need to follow. My OS is Ubuntu.

First I tried to install the latest development version:

```
 $ pip install -U git+https://github.com/bluet/proxybroker2.git.
```

At that point I didn't really know what to do there where several steps I tried.

Second I tried to install the docker image

> Use pre-built Docker image

```
$ docker pull bluet/proxybroker2
```

That didn't work

Then I installed  upx and objdump
upx
objdump (this tool is usually in the binutils package)

```
$ sudo apt install -y upx-ucl binutils # On Ubuntu / Debian
```

I also tried to build the executable
Build

```
pip install pyinstaller \
&& pip install . \
&& mkdir -p build \
&& cd build \
&& pyinstaller --onefile --name proxybroker --add-data "../proxybroker/data:data" --workpath ./tmp --distpath . --clean ../py2exe_entrypoint.py \
&& rm -rf tmp *.spec
```

I got an error message so that didnt work

The error message:

> ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found

Answer (score 0):

You can run the proxybroker docker container like this

> docker pull bluet/proxybroker2

> docker run bluet/proxybroker2 find --types HTTP HTTPS --lvl High --countries US --strict -l 10